# How to CSS if..else to change body background-color

Tags: css, if-statement

I got a CSS-related issue..

How can we perform if/else in CSS...
for example, i have a CSS file named main.css and two HTML pages namely a.html and b.html.

Inside body {} element (main.css) , the background-color will always be #dad4d4.
For a.html, the body will inherit this color property, but for b.html, i want the body background-color to be changed to #eae1e2.

How to make this a success?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse functions within a standard .css file.

However, a solution to what you want to do:

```
body.a {
    background-color: red;
}

body.b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Then simply use `<body class="a">` or `<body class="b">`on each respective page.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `id` or `class` attribute on your `<body>` element.

For example, on `a.html` it would be `<body id="a">` and on `b.html` it would be `<body id="b">`. You can then do:

```
body#a {
    background-color: blue;
}

body#b {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: If you are thinking both html files are in plain structure (both got their own <html> and <body> elements),this solution is okay. Actually, I have another file called index.tpl that will draw out the basic structure of the website where <html> and <body> elements are defined here. having said that, a.html and b.html only have <table>, <tr> and <td> elements....so, they are under the same <body>, how can we adapt the solution in this kind of structure?

Comment: Before I forget, the <body> element inside index.tpl has another class already defined. So, the option here to use body id

Comment: @steveVai: Put some conditional code in `index.tpl` to add the id or class, obviously. You can also add as many classes as you want, there is no limit there.

Answer (score 0):

You could give your body a class to achieve this.
In a.html your body will have class 'a', in b.html class 'b'.
Each class can then have it's own properties.

As far as I know if else is not possible in CSS